# Wildcard functionality on a user input in Powershell

Tags: powershell, input, wildcard

I'm currently writing a powershell script that takes in user input and searches for all items with a similar name in the directory.

```
$filename = '*test*.*'
$searchinfolder = 'C:\example'
Get-ChildItem -Path $searchinfolder -Filter $filename -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}
```

What I require is to have it accept user input while maintaining the functionality of the first line. So far I've used:

```
 $filename = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input word'
```

What would I have to do to maintain the functionality? e.g.
It finds folders test and test1

Comment: put it into a string that contains the desired added wildcards. something like `'*{0}*.*' -f $FileName` seems likely to work.

Comment: Yep that seems to have worked. Thanks @Lee_Dailey.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped somewhat ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lee_Dailey gave the solution in the comments.

```
$filename = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input word'
$filename = '*{0}*.*' -f $fileName
Get-ChildItem -Path $searchinfolder -Filter $filename -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}
```